# Make jQuery Deferred / Promises and AngularJS $q Deferred / Promises compatible

Tags: angularjs, jquery-deferred, q

I have some old JavaScript libraries that use [jQuery promises](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) as return objects from function calls. I'm now using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) which uses the [$q service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) (inspired by the [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)).
Does anybody have some generic JavaScript code to make these two different promise implementations compatible, so that jQuery promises can be used as if it where $q promises? Or something similar?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I knew this one, but it's cumbersome to apply it everywhere. The answer below is more what I (and probably others) was looking for.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Third party promises can be wrapped with `$q.when(thirdPartyPromise)` to be converted into $q promises. When the `thirdPartyPromise` resolves, the $q promise resolves accordingly and `$scope.$apply()` is called.

Comment: I’m glad $q picked that up from Q as well. The trick is that anything that implements `promise.then(cb, eb)` can be cast to a promise of another type, ignoring the return value.  It’s called “thenability”.

Comment: @KrisKowal, if the `$q.when()` wrapper woks, then presumably so will the simple form of coercion `$q(thirdPartyPromise)`?

Comment: @KrisKowal I wish Angular had adopted the entire Q library :)